# Can I use 'nesting' with Scala abstract types to simplify class definitions?

Tags: scala, types

I'm struggling a bit to understand how to use Scala's abstract types in as DRY/simple a way as possible. Let's say I have the following:

```
trait Product
trait Pallet[A <: Product]
class Import[
  A <: Product,
  B <: Pallet[A]] {

  def offload(): List[A] = {
    ...
  } 
}

class Fridge extends Product
class FridgePallet extends Pallet[Fridge]

val fridges = new Import[Fridge, FridgePallet]()
```

This works, but it feels a little verbose - given that the compiler knows `FridgePallet` is typed with `Fridge`, is there a way of simplifying the `Import` class's typing to remove the need for the explicit `A <: Product` declaration? I guess I'm looking for something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
class Import[B <: Pallet[A <: Product]] {
  def offload(): List[A] = ...
}
val fridges = new Import[FridgePallet]()
```

I've also tried replacing the `A`s with `_`s - but then I have to use `.asInstanceOf[List[Fridge]]` casting to get the type-specificity back on the `offload()` output.

What am I missing/not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this while staying with generic types, but if you can use type members instead, you get this:

```
trait Product
trait Pallet {
  type A <: Product
}
class Import[B <: Pallet] {
  def offload(): List[B#A] = { ... }
}

class Fridge extends Product
class FridgePallet extends Pallet {
  type A = Fridge
}

val fridges = new Import[FridgePallet]()
```

Comment: Many thanks **Alexey** - this works: `offload` returns a `List[Fridge]`. I believe you're right - there's no way to do this with generic types, and I'm not sure there's a way to get **iron9light**'s hybrid approach (generic type sets a type member in the parent trait) working...

Answer (score 2):

```
trait Pallet[A <: Product] {
  type ptype = A
}

class Import[P <: Pallet[_]] {
  def offload(): List[P#ptype] = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks iron9light - this is nice and succinct, unfortunately `List[P#ptype]` resolves into a `List[Any]` on use, so I don't really gain anything...